# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter in JQuery and asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, linq, web-services

I'm a newbie in Jquery Ajax. I need your help. I want to check Username Exist in my DB and display text beside span element. I have already done reference some topics but i can't resolve it

`{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027username\u0027.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary 2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target,IDictionary 2 parameters)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary 2 rawParams)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"} *`

In aspx

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="Server" name="username" class="inputbox frontlogin"/><span id="checkReturn"></span>
```

In code behind

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool KiemTraLogin(string username)
{
    CommonData dt = new CommonData();
    bool check = false;
    DataTable tb = dt.TruyVanTheoTenDangNhap(username);
    if (tb.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        check = false;
    }
    else
        check = true;
    return check;
}
```

In JavaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j("#<%=txtusername.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
            $j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Register.aspx/KiemTraLogin",
                data: "{'Username':'" + $j("#<%=txtusername.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (message) {
                    if (message.d == false) {
                        $j("#checkReturn").css({
                            "color": "red",
                            "font-weight": "bold",
                            "font-size": "small",
                            "padding-left": "5px"
                        });
                        $j("#checkReturn").text("Username Exist!");

                        $j("#btnSubmit").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $j("#checkReturn").css({
                            "color": "green",
                            "font-weight": "bold",
                            "font-size": "small",
                            "padding-left": "5px"
                        });
                        $j("#btnInsert").show();
                        $j("#checkReturn").text("UserName OK")
                    }
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {

                    $j("#checkReturn").text(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Store Procedure

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spTB_TruyVanTheoTenDangNhap] @TenDangNhap nvarchar(50)as select Username from Accinfo where Username = @TenDangNhap
```

Linq Code

```
  public DataTable TruyVanTheoTenDangNhap(string TenDangNhap)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTB_TruyVanTheoTenDangNhap");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TenDangNhap", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = TenDangNhap;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return dt;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The javascript is embedded into the page or is loaded as a resource? The call to #<%=something.ClientID %> might not work

Comment: what about for you data string just doing "{Username: Dude}" instead of the jquery and see if that resolves your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a local variable to hold your JSON object.  Then use a browser's developer tools to set a break point and step through your JQuery.  Then check to see what your JQuery selector is returning.

```
    var userModel = { Username: $j("#<%=txtusername.ClientID %>").val() };
    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Register.aspx/KiemTraLogin",
        data: userModel,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```